# If statements in tests

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a Parametrized test class with bunch of unit tests that generally control the creation of custom email messages. Right now class has a lot of test which depend on factor(s) used in parametrized class, the flow of the tests is the same for every test. The example of a test:

```
@Test
public void testRecipientsCount() {
    assertEquals(3, recipientsCount);
}
```

I had to add extra funcionality to my email class that adds some extra internal emails to the list of recipients, and that only happens for some of the cases and that leads to my problem.

Lets say I want to assert the amount of messages created. For the old test it was the same for each case, but now its different depending on cases. The most intuitive way for me was to add if statements:

```
@Test
public void testRecipientsCount(){
    if(something) {
        assertEquals(3, recipientsCount);
    }
    else {
        assertEquals(4, recipientsCount);
    }
}
...
```

but my more experienced co-worker says we should avoid ifs in test classes (and I kinda agree on that).

I thought that splitting test on two test classess may work, but that would lead to redundant code in both classes (I still have to check if non-iternal messages were created, their size, content etc.), and a few lines added for one of them.

My question is: how do I do this so I don't use if's or loads of redundant code (not using parametrized class would produce even more redundant code)?

Comment: `adds some extra internal emails to the list of recipients`. Is that list of internal addresses injected into the class? If so, you just wipe that list for most of the tests, and have one or two `testInternalMail` tests that DO populate that list

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Parametrized test class. Added test cases you suggest would run for every set of arguments, and the assertions would be different for some. Your solution would work without Parametrized class, but I kinda want to avoid that.

Comment: Could you change your posted code to a more complete (but still small and fake) test class, so we can understand how you set up your parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion a Junit should be read like a protocol.
That means you can write redundant code to make the test case better readable.
Write a testcase for each possible if-statement in your business logic as well as the negative cases. Thats the only way to get a 100% test coverage.
I use the structure:

```
- testdata preparation
- executing logic
- check results
- clear data
```

Furthermore you should write complex asserts of big objects in own abstract classes:

```
abstract class YourBusinessObjectAssert{
  public static void assertYourBussinessObjectIsValid(YourBusinessObject pYourBusinessObject,       Collection<YourBusinessObject> pAllYourBusinessObject) {
for (YourBusinessObject lYourBusinessObject : pAllYourBusinessObject) {
  if (lYourBusinessObject.isTechnicalEqual(pYourBusinessObject)) {
    return;
  }
}
assertFalse("Could not find requested YourBusinessObject in List<YourBusinessObject>!", true);
}
}
```

it will reduce the complexity of your code and you're making it available to other developers.

Answer (score 1):

A unit test should, in my opinion, test only one thing if possible.  As such I'd say that if you need an if statement then you probably need more than one unit test - one for each block in the if/else code.

If possible I'd say a test should read like a story - my preferred layout (and its not my idea :-) - its fairly widely used) is:

```
- given:  do setup etc
- when:  the place you actually execute/call the thing under test
- expect: verify the result
```

Another advantage of a unit test testing only one thing is that when a failure occurs its unambiguous what the cause was - if you have a long test with many possible outcomes it becomes much harder to reason why a test has failed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to cleanly do what you're after in a parametrized test. If you need different test case behavior based on which parameter for some features, you might just be better off testing those features separately - in different test classes that are not parametrized.

If you really do want to keep everything in the parametrized test classes, I would be inclined to make a helper function so that your example test at least reads as a simple assertion:

```
@Test
public void testRecipientsCount(){
    assertEquals(expectedCount(something), recipientsCount)
}

private int expectedCount(boolean which) {
    if (something){
       return 3;
    }
    else {
       return 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a private method that tests the things that are common for each method? Something like (but probably with some input parameter for the `testCommonStuff()` method):

```
@Test
public void testRecipientsCountA(){
   testCommonStuff();
   // Assert stuff for test A
}

@Test
public void testRecipientsCountB(){
   testCommonStuff();
   // Assert stuff for test B
}

private void testCommonStuff() {
   // Assert common stuff
}
```

This way you don't get redundant code and you can split your test into smaller tests. Also you make your tests less error prone IF they should actually test the same things. You will still know which test that failed, so traceability should be no problem.

Comment: I use Parametrized class, and it would run both of your test cases for each set of arguments. Correct way is to run only one, depending on the actual argument.

Comment: @Badman6 I don't fully get it. You say "but that would lead to redundant code in both classes (I still have to check if non-iternal messages were created, their size, content etc.)". Does that not mean that you have reduntant code in one or more test methods? If so, you can have it in an own private method like above and call it from each of the methods that should run it.

Comment: Its not that. Recipient count depends on a parameter specified in an argument provider for parameter class. If I wanna keep Parametrized class redundant code would be a result of splitting my tests into 2 classes (one for cases with, one without internal recipients). For tests classes sharing code isn't really an option. You solution is ok, just not for Parametrized class

Comment: @Badman6 I still don't fully understand. :) If you really have reduntant code, it SHOULD be possible to move it to a separate method. If not, it doesn't really sound redundant to me.